# How to create a Folder (Directory) property editor for my component?

Tags: delphi, components, delphi-2010, custom-component, propertyeditor

Delphi 2010

How to create a Folder (Directory) property editor for my component?

I was able to easily create one for a FileName property using:

```
TFileProperty = class(TStringProperty)  
public  
  function GetAttributes: TPropertyAttributes; override;  
  procedure Edit; override;  
end;  

RegisterPropertyEditor(TypeInfo(TFileName),nil, '', TFileProperty);
```

I think it may take alittle more work, as i think i need to create a class to register, and somehow call selDir api routine or something

thanks for any help you may offer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think i got something to work, unless someone else can come up with something better

```
type  
  TFolderName = String;  

  TFolderNameProperty = class(TStringProperty)  
  public  
    function GetAttributes: TPropertyAttributes; override;  
    procedure Edit; override;  
  end;  

function TFolderNameProperty.GetAttributes: TPropertyAttributes;  
begin  
  Result := [paDialog]  
end {GetAttributes}; 

procedure TFolderNameProperty.Edit;  
var  
  Dir: String;  
begin  
  SelectDirectory('Select a directory', '', Dir)  
  SetValue(Dir);  
end {Edit};  

procedure Register;  
begin  
  RegisterPropertyEditor(TypeInfo(TFolderName),nil, '', TFolderNameProperty)  
end;
```

Comment: Change your definition of the property type like so: `TFolderName = type string`. That gives the type new RTTI distinct from that of the built-in `string` type. Without it, your property editor will apply to *all* `string` properties, not just the ones declared as `TFolderName`. Compare to `TFileName`.

Comment: In addition to what @Rob said, you might also want to 1) Initialize Dir (even if it's to an empty string) before using it (just as a good habit to get into), and 2) Check the result of the call to SelectDirectory() before blindly using Dir to set a property. (SelectDirectory returns a Boolean indicating whether a directory was selected or the dialog was cancelled.)